# Inlining after parsing parameters to optimize algorithm speed

Tags: java, c++, performance, programming-languages, inline

Lets say you need to implement a very fast algorithm to solve some problem, it may depend on a set of parameters that you will fetch into memory from some data source. Let say these parameters will act like constants once they have been parsed (but are still problem dependent). If these constants were known to begin with and written explicitly in the source code, I would expect the compiler to inline them, which may give nice speed improvements assuming those parameters are frequently accessed near the bottleneck. However if they are parsed from an external source by the program after it was compiled, they will typically not be inlined, even if you allocate your object with final variables.
I guess a trick could be to hold a copy of the efficient object for each set of values, where each set of value is written explictly in the code. Then one could use the relevant object. But this would be memory costly and code would grow exponentially.
Another idea could be to compile code dynamically, after the set of parameters was parsed.

My question is: is there something that was ever designed to deal with this issue elegantly, more specifically in Java/C++.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you want to use a c++ `template` and instantiate for a bunch of likely constant values.

Comment: But if I have ten boolean values, thats already 2^10=1024 possibilities. Now there can be integers and doubles, it grows exponentially. These constants may also control code flow, so inlining could help avoid branching. The goal is to build customizable and still fast software.

Comment: Then I don't know what you mean by *"hold a copy of the efficient object for each set of values, where each set of value is written explictly in the code."*

Comment: You got what I mean, I just didn't think its very elegant an idea. I was wondering if there is a better way. Or does c++ template inline constants at run time?

Comment: This problem is constantly being optimized in the various regex implementations and libraries. There is more than one way to go about this. If you think about it you could even include a compiler in your program and then load the compiled code as a shared library.

Comment: Template arguments are necessarily compile-time constants, so they will be inlined at compile time and don't come into play at run time. To do what you want in c++ would require that the relevant algorithm be recompiled when the constants become known. You would need to supply or embed a compiler and the source code of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, using a JDK, you can do the following:

1. Read the constants
2. Write a class that contains your code in such a way that you print your parameter set in the form of `final static public` class members. Then append the code for your algorithm (which you have somewhere in a String).
3. Compile this with the internal JDK compiler (memory to memory compilation is possible)
4. Load the resulting class and start it at some static method. Or make a class instance and work with that.

This works because the java compiler treats `final static` variables as immutable constants.

Whether this makes your code really faster? I doubt it. For this method to yield benefits, it would have to run long enough to compensate for the 2 to 3 seconds you need for compilation, class loading, etc.